# Merging a chunked file using streams corrupts end file

Tags: elixir

I'm working on a chunked upload feature. Currently I'm trying to merge together the chunks to create back the original file. Initially I had implemented this without streams like so:

```
{:ok, full_file_path} = Briefly.create()

state.upload_chunk_files
|> Enum.sort(&sort_chunk_paths/2)
|> Enum.reduce(File.open!(full_file_path, [:append]), &build_file/2)

...

defp build_file(chunk_path, full_file) do
  IO.binwrite(full_file, File.read!(elem(chunk_path, 1)))
  full_file
end
```

`upload_chunk_files` is a keyword list that looks like this

```
["1": "./data/1234/1", "2": "./data/1234/2"]
```

This initial implementation works fine until I starting testing the memory usage. I realized even though I'm only writing to the file chunk by chunk by the time all the chunks are read the entire file is in memory. My initial thought, coming from GO(lang), was once the read chunk is written to the file it would be removed from memory.

So I started looking into streams and came up with this implementation

```
state.upload_chunk_files
|> Enum.sort(&sort_chunk_paths/2)
|> Enum.reduce(File.stream!(full_file_path, [:append], 200_000), &build_file/2)
 
...

defp build_file(chunk_path, full_file) do
  Stream.into(File.stream!(elem(chunk_path, 1)), full_file) |> Stream.run()
  full_file
end
```

The proper amount of bytes are transferred over to the "full file"; however when I try to open it, it is corrupted. I tried different modes for opening the stream but could not get it to open up the file properly.

Answer (score 0):

`Stream.into/3` immediately followed by `Stream.run/1` does not make much sense.

The initial implementation was fine. I am not sure how it relates to the mutability of the language, but all the languages with garbage collection do require some time (or pressure) to run GC and hence clean the not-used memory up.

While you might explicitly run GC between calls to `IO.binwrite/2`, it’s an antipattern. If there will be a lack of memory, GC would be run by VM itself.

If you want to avoid memory usage at all, I’d stick to delegation to system `cat` command with [`System.cmd/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#cmd/3).

Comment: Why does using `Stream.run/1` after `Stream.into/3` not make much sense? What ever was added to the stream won't be executed until run is called. I don't mind some memory usage but I don't want to use up the file of the size in memory. I think Streams are the proper solution I'm just missing something that is corrupting the file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help from the elixir forum someone brought up this point.

I think your approach should work as well but you are reading file with default line_or_bytes option which is :line, which normalizes the bytes. I have been bitten by this more than once.

To illustrate what I mean:

```
File.write!("test.txt", "test\r\nok")

File.stream!("test.txt", [], :line)
|> Enum.join("")
|> byte_size()
|> IO.inspect(label: "line")

File.stream!("test.txt", [], 10)
|> Enum.join("")
|> byte_size()
|> IO.inspect(label: "bytes")
```

Which outputs

```
line: 7
bytes: 8
```

From the docs:

```
`The line_or_bytes argument configures how the file is read when streaming, by :line (default) or by a given number of bytes. When using the :line option, CRLF line breaks (" ") are normalized to LF (" ").`
```

So the issue the chunked file was being read as line when it should be read by bytes. Simply making it read by bytes fixes the issue.

```
defp build_file(chunk_path, full_file) do
  Stream.into(File.stream!(chunk_path, [], 200_000), full_file) 
  |> Stream.run()

  full_file
end
```